# Using templates to parameterize types in interface mapping a legacy C interface

Tags: c++, templates

I have a (legacy) c interface looking something like this:

```
// c interface
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {
    type_1 = 0, /* native type: uint8_t */
    type_2 = 1, /* native type: double */
    // ... lots of more types defined ...
} thing_type_t;

void thing_set(thing_type_t type, size_t type_size, void* value);
void thing_get(thing_type_t type, size_t type_size, void* return_value);

void thing_set_type_1(uint8_t value);
void thing_get_type_1(uint8_t *value);

void thing_set_type_2(double value);
void thing_get_type_2(double *value);

// ...
```

So basically you can set *thing*, and based on which `thing_type_t` you choose there is a corresponding native type. This interface I cannot change.

Now I want to do a C++ interface utilising type polymorphism, so I from a client can do something like:

```
// C++ client
#include <cstdint>

int main(void)
{
    Thing thing;
    thing.set(std::uint8_t(42));
    thing.set(42.0);

    auto uivalue = thing.get<std::uint8_t>();
    auto dvalue = thing.get<double>();

    return 0;
}
```

It does not have to be exactly like this, but the idea is that the client do not have to worry about the internal `thing_type_t` types, but just uses the corresponding native types.

What I have come up with is using templates like this:

```
// C++ interface
#include <cstdint>

class Thing
{
public:
    template <typename T> void set(T value);
    template <typename T> T get();
};

template <> void Thing::set(uint8_t value)
{
    thing_set(type_1, sizeof value, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&value));
}
template <> std::uint8_t Thing::get()
{
    uint8_t ret = 0;
    thing_get(type_1, sizeof ret, &ret);
    return ret;
}

template <> void Thing::set(double value)
{
    thing_set(type_2, sizeof value, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&value));
}
template <> double Thing::get()
{
    double ret = 0;
    thing_get(type_2, sizeof ret, &ret);
    return ret;
}
```

I.e. I am doing type specialisation for each of the `thing_type_t` which results in bloated code with lots and lots of repeated code.

**How do I simplify this so I can express the mapping between `thing_type_t` and native type without duplicating the get/set function again and again?**

I feel like I should be able somehow parameterize the get and set functions with both the `thing_type_t` and native type as well as the mapping. But I cannot figure out how to do that.

[Online editable example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1c301544a2c2d20)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the only thing that changes between implementations is the first argument I'd just specialise that part:

```
class Thing
{
public:
    template <typename T> void set(T value)
    {
        thing_set(getType<T>(value), sizeof value, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&value));
    }
    template <typename T> T get()
    {
        T ret = 0;
        thing_get(getType<T>(ret), sizeof ret, &ret);
        return ret;
    }

private:
    template <typename T> thing_type_t getType(T);
};

template <> thing_type_t Thing::getType(uint8_t)
{
    return type_1;
}
template <> thing_type_t Thing::getType(double)
{
    return type_2;
}
```

Comment: And it is this simple of cause. :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

macroses can help in such cases:

## typemap.h

```
macro(type_1, std::uint8_t)
```

## thing.h

```
class Thing
{
public:
    template <typename T> void set(T value);
    template <typename T> T get();
};

#define macro(thing_type, actual_type) template <> void Thing::set(actual_type value) \
{\
    thing_set(thing_type, sizeof value, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&value));\
}\
#include <typemap.h>
#undef macro 

#define macro(thing_type, actual_type) template <> actual_type Thing::get()\
{\
    actual_type ret = 0;\
    thing_get(thing_type, sizeof ret, &ret);\
    return ret;\
}\
#include <typemap.h>
#undef macro
```

so in the end you only have to modify typemap.h to add/remove specializations